# Awning window not holding open

Tags: windows

The track and small block in an awning window was recently cleaned (by accident?), and now no longer stays open under the windows weight. Is this anything to do with a lubricant or grease which should be applied again? Any help greatly appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question; have you tried contacting the manufacturer? (Who is the manufacturer?)

Comment: Seems to me that applying lubricant would would only allow it to slide closed more easily...

Answer (score 1):

Only guessing, but many cleaning agents are made up of chemicals (bases) that tend to be slick which helps in most cleaning situations.  Perhaps clean the inside of the track with acetone or brake parts cleaner to remove any of the former cleaning residue.  Perhaps that will restore the friction needed to hold the awning open.